# Ethernet frame transmission via raw socket

Tags: c, linux, sockets

My intent is to write a function which takes as parameter a buffer holding an entire ethernet frame and sends it to a raw socket (so needed only for transmission).

Here the obvious steps:

```
sockfd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);
// ...
write(sockfd, buffer, buffer_len);
// ...
close(sockfd);
```

But the write function fails with an EXNIO error code: "No such device or address". I grab the packet content from a wireshark session, so it should be well formatted.

There are several examples on internet about sending a raw eth packet, but I haven't found anything using write() instead of sendto(), which requires the sockaddr_ll struct to be filled.

Has anyone experienced the same issue? Is using sendto() the only way to accomplish the task?

Thanks.

Note: the program runs as root.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a part of code which worked for me. In my understanding of things, write will not work as it is supposed to send a stream of chars. It can write to a file or to a TCP connection or similar. I think that raw packets are very different.

```
int sock;
sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, 0);
if (sock < 0) {
  printf("Can't get socket\n");
  exit(1);
}
/* Insist that we have header included */
int one = 1;
if (setsockopt (sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, &one, sizeof (one)) < 0) {
  printf ("Cannot set IP_HDRINCL!\n");
  exit(1);
}
...
struct sockaddr_in sockin;
sockin.sin_family = AF_INET;
sockin.sin_port = dest_port;
sockin.sin_addr.s_addr = dest_ip;
...
sendto (sock, buffer, bufferlen, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &sockin, sizeof (sockin));
...
close(sock);
```